# If the multiplication of matrices symmetric matrix, then they can be diagonalized

Tags: diagonalization

If the matrix **C** is the result of the multiplication of matrices **A** and **B**, and if is **C** symmetric matrix, then the matrices **A** and **B** can be diagonalized.

Is this statement always correct? If so, why?

Comment: Consider the case $B=A^{-1}$ for invertible matrices which cannot be diagonalized. Then $C=I$ is symmetric, but ...

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\quad B=A^{-1}.
$$
Then $C=I$ is symmetric, but $A$ and $B$ are not diagionalizable.

Answer (score 0):

If $A=B=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, then $AB$ is the null matrix, which is symmetric. But $A$ is not diagonalizable.